# Pandas convert columns type from list to np.array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, casting

I'm trying to apply a function to a pandas dataframe, such a function required two np.array as input and it fit them using a well defined model.

The point is that I'm not able to apply this function starting from the selected columns since their "rows" contain list read from a JSON file and not np.array.

Now, I've tried different solutions:

```
#Here is where I discover the problem

train_df['result'] = train_df.apply(my_function(train_df['col1'],train_df['col2']))

#so I've tried to cast the Series before passing them to the function in both these ways:

X_col1_casted = trai_df['col1'].dtype(np.array)
X_col2_casted = trai_df['col2'].dtype(np.array)
```

doesn't work.

```
X_col1_casted = trai_df['col1'].astype(np.array)
X_col2_casted = trai_df['col2'].astype(np.array)
```

doesn't work.

```
X_col1_casted = trai_df['col1'].dtype(np.array)
X_col2_casted = trai_df['col2'].dtype(np.array)
```

does'nt work.

What I'm thinking to do now is a long procedure like:

starting from the uncasted column-series, convert them into list(), iterate on them apply the function to the np.array() single elements, and append the results into a temporary list. Once done I will convert this list into a new column. ( clearly, I don't know if it will work )

Does anyone of you know how to help me ?

EDIT:
I add one example to be clear:

The function assume to have as input two np.arrays. Now it has two lists since they are retrieved form a json file. The situation is this one:

```
col1        col2    result
[1,2,3]     [4,5,6]  [5,7,9]
[0,0,0]     [1,2,3]  [1,2,3]
```

Clearly the function is not the sum one, but a own function. For a moment assume that this sum can work only starting from arrays and not form lists, what should I do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `.values` attribute to convert it into an array.

Comment: may you also tell me how ? I need to use it to single cell elements, not to the whole columns in one shot. I need one array per row.

Comment: what do you mean *one array per row*? I understood from the question that you want to convert a whole column to a numpy array.

Comment: I've edited the question with an example. The functoin that work per row, assume to have as input np.array and not lists. That's the point. Hoping to be clear now.

Comment: I actually have the opposite requirement, My pandas dataframe have numpy.ndarray that I want to convert to list so that It cant be stored into DynamoDB table. Does anyone have any inputs on how can I do that

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `apply` to convert each element to it's equivalent array:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))

type(df['col1'].iloc[0])
numpy.ndarray
```

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[1,2,3],[0,0,0]]})
df
```

[image]

Comment: `df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(np.array)` works as well

Comment: I came here because I wanted to get a *one big np.array* from a column of type list (i.e. no pandas types at all). For those who want that you can do this: `np.stack(df['col1'])` (e.g. necessary for keras)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `pd.Series` on top of the list.
e.g.,

```
>>> X_train = df.col1.apply(pd.Series).to_numpy()

>>> type(X_train)
numpy.ndarray
```