# How to change array([list([ into array([])

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

I did tfidf with manual syntax and I got the results of the tf idf vector in the form of a data series. the data is as follows:

```
print(type(dataset["TFIDFVec"]))
print(dataset["TFIDFVec"])

<class pandas.core.series.Series>
0       [0.0, 0.6307448112902039, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1       [0.0, 0.0, 1.3985703304477997, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
```

I want to convert it to an array. I use to_numpy() code but it output list in array. what I tried is the following:

```
tfidffixarr = dataset["TFIDFVec"].to_numpy()
tfidffixarr

array([list([0.0, 0.6307448112902039, 0.0, 0.0,...,0.0]),
      list([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...,0.0])],
```

I want it to be jut like this:

```
[[0 0.6307448112902039 0,..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ,..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ,..., 0 0 0]]
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas convert columns type from list to np.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618678/pandas-convert-columns-type-from-list-to-np-array)

Comment: try doing `np.array(tfidffixarr.tolist())`

Answer (score 1):

To Python list:

```
list(dataset["TFIDFVec"])
```